# Automatically add hidden field to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to build a **[custom form builder](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-form-builder)** in `simple_form`, which add some hidden fields to a form without using `form.hidden_field`. I noticed that the `utf8` and `authenticity_token` hidden fields are automatically added to every form.

Is there a similar mechanism to add another custom hidden field, *but only to forms that are generated by my custom form builder*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret ist to use **[capture](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture)**, which allows you to get the HTML generated in the template. You can then add hidden fields using the `form.hidden_field` method (in fact any method), which returns the generated HTML directly.

```
def custom_form_for(object, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!.merge(builder: CustomFormBuilder)

  simple_form_for(object, *(args << options)) do |form|
    capture do
      block.call(form)
    end.tap do |content|
      content << form.hidden_field "foo", value: "bar"
      content << form.hidden_field "baz", value: "qux"
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know... started to feel really dumb.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of patching this at FormBuilder level, you can integrate this into a custom input:

```
class MagicInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::HiddenInput
  def input
    if object.condition?
      @builder.hidden_field(:hidden_field_name, value: "some value").html_safe
      # You could also call #super here (instead of the previous call)
      # because this extends HiddenInput (might be cleaner, depending on what you
      # want to achieve)
    end
  end
end
```

This custom input injects a hidden field into your form only if `object.condition?` is true.
Obviously you'll need to create the `#condition?` method on the object passed to your form (or replace this condition line with wathever floats your boat).

Then in your view you'd call it like:

```
= f.input :something, as: :magic
```

And your hidden field will appear only when `object.condition?` passes.

**Edit:** And for the juicy detials - the `utf8` and `authenticity_token` hidden fields are implemented in `form_tag` - not really in the FormBuilder: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/801e159ce2f4645f6839c94ab0febf97a0d8543d/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L713

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your `custom_form_for` mehtod like this

```
def custom_form_for(object, *args, &block)
  options = args.extract_options!
  simple_form_for(object, *(args << options.merge(:builder => CustomFormBuilder))) do |form|
    block.call(form) << form.input_field(:field, :as => :hidden, :value => 'value')
  end
end
```

The hidden field will be the last element of the form; if you switch the lines it will be the first.

Comment: This won't work. `simple_form_for` returns a string (more exact: a `SafeBuffer`). You can't call `.hidden_field` on that.

Comment: @iblue you are right. Fixed that one - seems I was too much in a hurry.

Comment: This doesn't work either. `block.call(form)` returns `Fixnum`.